# Chrome DevTools removes Tabs and LIne breaks when saving Changes to Disk

Tags: css, google-chrome, formatting, google-chrome-devtools, minify

When I make CSS changes with the Chrome DevTools-Elements-Inspector the Changes are saved automatically to disk (thanks to workspaces).

But there is a problem with this: DevTools removes Tabs and Line breaks when saving to Disk.

It seems Chrome DevTools is minifying my CSS changes.

**Is this a new Chrome Feature?
Can this be turned off?**

I want linebreakes and spaces to be preserved in the CSS file.

[image]

Edit: I have now found out that the Minifying does not happen with Chrome version 99. The problem described above occurs with version 101. Unfortunately I still haven't found a way to turn off the Minifying (unless I install an older Chrome version). I can't find a checkbox to disable it.

Answer (score 0):

That's the minify checkbox:

It's off by default, and is used for saving your CSS file in a minified format. It can be turned off to save your file with line breaks, tabs, and whitespace.
It doesn't do that by default because that usually results in a larger file, which means more data transferred and processed, and takes more time to parse. Minifying, which removes all unnecessary whitespace, typically results in a much smaller CSS file, which is generally a Good Thing.
You should generally leave it off unless you have a specific reason to save your CSS with the whitespace.
More info: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/devtools/element-inspector#save:

If you want to save whitespace in your styles, uncheck Minify in the file dialog that appears.
The changes are automatically saved to your stylesheet.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately your link doesn't work. Where can I find this checkbox to deactivate the Minifing? In the DevTools-Settings?